# PDO suprime colunas com nomes iguais

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo, mysqli

Percebi que ao utilizar o `PDO` para executar a consulta abaixo, os resultados são conflitantes com o `PhpMyadmin` e o `Console do Mysql`:

```
SELECT a.*, n.* FROM arquivo AS a INNER JOIN numeracao AS n ON 
                    (a.id_numeracao  =  n.id_numeracao) WHERE total_documentos=-1
```

A tabela `arquivo` tem uma estrutura parecida com essa:

> **Tabela arquivo:**  id_arquivo, nome,  numero,    **status**,  id_tipo_arquivo, 
>   dt_arquivamento,  id_desarquivamento,  id_usuario,  **id_numeracao**

A Tabela `numeração` é assim:

> **Tabela numeracao:**  **id_numeracao**,  numeracao,  id_tipo_arquivo,  **status**, 
>   total_documentos,  uso

As tabelas tem duas colunas em comum: "status" e "id_numeracao".

Se eu executar a consulta pelo `PhpMyadmin` ou `Console do Mysql` o resultado distingue as colunas de cada tabela. porém executando com o PDO as colunas em comum são suprimidas, e apenas uma é exibida.

Sei que o correto é as colunas terem nomes distintos ou utilizar alias mas, porque ocorre essa diferença nos resultados do PHP e do Mysql?

Estou executando a consulta desta forma:

```
$q = $conn->prepare($select);

if($q->execute()){                 
   $data = array();
   while ($row = $q->fetch($pdo_fetch)) {  
      $data[] = $row;   
   } 
}
```

Obs.: Testei as extensões `mysql` e `mysqli` e o resultado é igual.

Comment: A resposta do @bfavaretto é correta e resolve bem a situação atual, mas o ideal a médio prazo é não usar mais os asteriscos e sim por o nome das colunas individualmente. Por consequência, você pode usar `SELECT a.id_numeracao AS a_id_numeracao, n.id_numeracao AS n_id_numeracao` etc, e os nomes não vão mais conflitar, além do benefício de trafegar/processar somente os dados que realmente vai fazer uso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo [esta resposta do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525396/825789), você pode instruir o PDO a incluir os nomes da tabela no nome de cada coluna:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, true);
```

Com isso, os valores do seu exemplo seriam recuperados assim:

```
$id1 = $row['arquivo.id_numeracao'];
$id2 = $row['numeracao.id_numeracao'];
```

Comment: Obs: ainda não testei isso, respondo com base na resposta que indiquei.

Comment: Essa deve ser uma regra para as outras extensões do mysql para PHP, já que, pelo que testei o resultado foi o mesmo.