# Colunas com nomes iguais em uma consulta única, mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou a realizar uma consulta MySQL nesse estilo:

`select contents.*, users.* FROM users, contents`

entretando nas duas tabelas existem colunas com mesmo nome, e na hora de puxa-las com PHP ele resulta a primeira, porém eu quero ambas.

Existe alguma forma de pegar ambos dados dessas colunas sem que eu tenha que alterar cada nome de coluna? Eu pensei em colocar um prefixo na hora de resultar, algo assim, mas não sei se é funcional.

Comment: Tem muitas colunas com nomes iguais? a solução via sql é dar um alias (mudar o nome manualmente na consulta). Pelo php veja [PDO suprime colunas com nomes iguais](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8550/91)

Comment: Existe sim renomeando os nomes dos campos e passando isso na sua sql: exemplo `select contents.id, contents.descricao as contdescricao`.... e assim vai, para ter o nome único para cada item da sua sql

Comment: @rray só renomeando mesmo?

Comment: @rray vi sua opção para PHP, mas ele fará isso para todas as futuras consultas? Pois isso ocorre só em uma.

Comment: Ai depende de como o código está organizado, no caso vc marcar aquela configuração antes da consulta e final do método restar ou remove ela.

Comment: @rray ótimo, veja, eu uso MySQLI, existe uma função similar (do setAttribute) para ele? Estou  a pesquisar e ainda não encontrei.

Comment: @Elaine uma dica que eu vou dar que acho que te ajudaria a entender, se você não precisa de todos os campos na junção de `contents` e `user`,  a melhor forma de otimizar a sua `SQL` ( que muitas vezes é um ladrão de desempenho do sistema ) e como está na resposta do Allan Andrade, ou seja, especificando o que precisa e renomeando campos que possui o nome igual.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, sim eu entendo, mas como são mais de 30 colunas e todas são usadas no código PHP, eu preciso tentar todas as opções..

Comment: @Elaine entendo perfeitamente a minha ressalva era se ia utilizar todos os campos. Também tem um problema ai, porque 30 campos será que não caberia uma normalização ai... !!! são dicas ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu não entendi a sua pergunta, qualquer coisa me chame no chat. Elaine parece que não essa opção para o MySQLi.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic acredito que seja [isso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15025/91) e essas duas consultas não são equivalente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
select contents.nome_igual as nome1, users.nome_igual as nome2 FROM users, contents
```