# Distinguir campos iguais em um SELECT com LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Em um `SELECT` feito em duas tabelas com campos parecidos eu gostaria de distinguir o campo de cada tabela na hora de mostrar os resultados. Por exemplo:

```
$sql = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT a.*, b.*
                                FROM tabela_a a
                                LEFT JOIN tabela b ON
                                a.campo = b.campo");
$sql->execute();
$dados = $sql->fetch();
```

Vamos imaginar que em ambas as tabelas eu tenha o campo `data` e eu gostaria de mostrar o campo de cada um distinguido:

```
 $dados["a.data"] ou $dados["b.data"]
```

Ao dar um `print_r` em `$dados` as chaves do array são nomeadas pela tabela a, enquanto as colunas da da tabela b que são iguais as da tabela a são enumerados de forma crescente como um array comum, existe alguma forma de exibir os dados de cada uma separado?

Obs: para minificar a pergunta eu não coloquei `while` na pesquisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você vai precisar apelidar essas colunas específicas manualmente para conseguir "pega-las" depois dentro do while.

#### Exemplo

```
$sql = BD::conn()->prepare(
    "SELECT 
    a.campo1, a.campo2, a.campo3, a.campo_igual as a_campo_igual,
    b.campo1, b.campo2, b.campo3, b.campo_igual as b_campo_igual
    FROM tabela_a a
    LEFT JOIN tabela b ON a.campo = b.campo"
);
```

#### Caso queira adicionar a tabela como prefixo de cada coluna

Assim você poderá pegar os "campos iguais" sem problema no while.

```
// array para informar qual coluna pertence a qual tabela
// irei processar isso depois para formar o apelido "tabela_x_coluna_y"
// é muito provável que este array seja preciso montar manualmente, 
// mas irá facilitar sua vida no SELECT
$tabelas = [
    'tabela_a' => [
        'campo1',
        'campo2',
        'campo3',
        'campo_igual',
    ],
    'tabela_b' => [
        'campo1',
        'campo2',
        'campo3',
        'campo_igual',
    ]
];

// array com as colunas apelidadas, é preenchido no foreach abaixo
// vou usar este array em um implode depois para facilitar o uso da vírgula que separa cada coluna
$columnsSql = [];

foreach ($tabelas as $tabela => $colunas) {  
    foreach ($colunas as $coluna) {
        $colunaDB      = $tabela.'.'.$coluna; // é a coluna com prefixo da tabela
        $colunaApelido = $tabela.'_'.$coluna; // é a coluna com apelido, para você poder pegar depois no while

        $columnsSql[] = $colunaDB.' AS '.$colunaApelido
    }
}

$sql = BD::conn()->prepare(
    "SELECT ".implode(', ', $columnsSql)."
    FROM tabela_a a
    LEFT JOIN tabela b ON a.campo = b.campo"
);
```

#### ATUALIZAÇÃO

Segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.constants.php) na conexão do PDO você pode setar o atributo `PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES` para:

> Usa o nome da tabela como prefixo em cada nome de coluna retornado no result set. O nome da tabela e o nome da coluna são separados por um caracter decimal (.). O suporte para este atributo está no level driver; pode não ser suportado pelo seu driver.

Créditos: [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8556/21593) e [esta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525396/2312615).

Comment: Se forem tabelas com muitas colunas, não existe uma solução mais fácil?

Comment: @LeoLetto Infelizmente não, a não ser que você queira alterar toda sua query manualmente para que toda coluna tenha como prefixo o nome da tabela.

Comment: Tem algum link de referência ou você poderia me ajudar a entender como posso fazer isso?

Comment: @LeoLetto editei a resposta com o código que adiciona a tabela como prefixo, veja se te ajuda.

Comment: @LeoLetto atualizei a resposta com uma opção bem mais prática, dê uma olhada por favor e veja se funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar alias para os seus campos no seu select, assim eles ficariam com nomes destintos, ex:

```
SELECT a.campo1 as campo1A, a.campo2 as campo2A, a.data as dataA, b.data as dataB
FROM tabela_a a
LEFT JOIN tabela b ON
a.campo = b.campo
```